# can't post from app to another app in server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, routes

I have 2 apps running on my localhost on port 3000 and 9000 (rails 2 and sinatra app).
I have set up a controller in the rails app (without any specific model or view) in `app/controllers/finance_service.rb`

```
class FinanceServiceController < ApplicationController
    def after_token_create 
        p "after token create function: #{params.inspect}"
    end
end
```

and had set up a route like so :

`map.finance_service '/finance_service' , :controller => "finance_service", :action => "after_token_create"`

and When I access it on the url `http://localhost:3000/finance_service`

I get error on template missing, but that's fine because it means the route is working (I am using it as a service api to the another app).

when trying to access the method from the other app using `httparty gem` like so :

```
HTTParty.post("http://localhost:3000/FinanceServiceController/after_token_create", :body => post_params)
```

I get an error on the rails app-

```
myapp/public/404.html (method_not_allowed)
```

Also tried from advanced Rest client app, and I get the same error.

Comment: How does your routes.rb file look for the rails 2 app? Are the correct entries for finance_service route?

Comment: it's there in the question

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the request be like this? since the route matcher is /finance_service

```
HTTParty.post("http://localhost:3000/finance_service", :body => post_params)
```

Comment: you say "I get error on template missing, but that's fine because it means the route is working (I am using it as a service api to the another app).", fix that first, maybe you get a "method not allowed" because it returns an error, every action should render something, at least do 'render :text => "after token create function: #{params.inspect}"' instead of 'p "...."'